# Why does the first image show briefly while the second and third images display much longer?

Tags: css, css-animations

In the following code the first image shows briefly while the second and third images display much longer. Why does the first image go by so quick?

I'm attempting to learn CSS animation. I believe I have the code correct however the intervals between images are not the same. The interval between the first and second image is very brief where the interval between second and third image is longer.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1002722/pexels-photo-1002722.jpeg? auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint;");
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 7s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1002722/pexels-photo-1002722.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint")
  }
  25% {
    background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/6087668/pexels-photo-6087668.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint")
  }
  100% {
    background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/10443212/pexels-photo-10443212.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint")
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Animation</h1>

<div></div>

<p><b>Note:</b> When an animation is finished, it goes back to its original style.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, photo 10443212 will be shown at 100% and then almost immediately when the animation returns to 0% the photo 1002722 will be shown.

You should use 1/3rd intervals:

```
    @keyframes example {
    0%  {background:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1002722/pexels-photo-1002722.jpeg? 
    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint")
    }
      
    33%  {background:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/6087668/pexels-photo-6087668.jpeg? 
    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint")
      }
        
     66%  {background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/10443212/pexels-photo-10443212.jpeg? 
    auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=400&h=250&fit=crop&crop=focalpoint")
     }
    }
```